# Thingsboard container doesn't update on config change

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, cassandra, thingsboard

I am trying to update database config (parameters such as certain ports, db address etc.). Unfortunately only some ports change according to logs.

I am using following dockerfile

```
FROM thingsboard/tb-cassandra #repo link https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/tree/master/msa/tb
RUN sed -i "s/:5683/:12090/g" /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml #this one works
RUN sed -i "s/localhost:5432/postgres:5432/g" /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml #this one doesnt update anything
```

What can cause such a behavior? Is there a way to deploy the solution

Comment: Have you tried extracting the file from the running container and running the sed command on your machine?

Comment: The contents were changed, The reason was that the parent container has already set some of the ENV variables, which couldn't be overdriven by config file, the solution was to change them.